# How are the missing events replayed?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am trying to learn more about CQRS and Event Sourcing (Event Store).

My understanding is that a message queue/bus is not normally used in this scenario - a message bus can be used to facilitate communication between Microservices, however it is not typically used specifically for CQRS.  However, the way I see it at the moment - a message bus would be very useful guaranteeing that the read model is eventually in sync hence eventual consistency e.g. when the server hosting the read model database is brought back online.

I understand that eventual consistency is often acceptable with CQRS.  My question is; how does the read side know it is out of sync with the write side? For example, lets say there are 2,000,000 events created in Event Store on a typical day and 1,999,050 are also written to the read store.  The remaining  950 events are not written because of a software bug somewhere or because the server hosting the read model is offline for a few secondsetc.  How does eventual consistency work here? How does the application know to replay the 950 events that are missing at the end of the day or the x events that were missed because of the downtime ten minutes ago?

I have read questions on here over the last week or so, which talk about messages being replayed from event store e.g. this one: [CQRS - Event replay for read side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818395/cqrs-event-replay-for-read-side), however none talk about how this is done.  Do I need to setup a scheduled task that runs once per day and replays all events that were created since the date the scheduled task last succeeded?  Is there a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used two approaches in my projects, depending on the requirements:

1. **Synchronous, in-process** Readmodels. After the events are persisted, in the same request lifetime, in the same process, the Readmodels are fed with those events. In case of a Readmodel's failure (bug or catchable error/exception) the error is logged and that Readmodel is just skipped and the next Readmodel is fed with the events and so on. Then follow the Sagas, that may generate commands that generate more events and the cycle is repeated.

I use this approach when the impact of a Readmodel's failure is acceptable by the business, when the readiness of a Readmodel's data is more important than the risk of failure. For example, they wanted the data immediately available in the UI.

The error log should be easily accessible on some admin panel so someone would look at it in case a client reports inconsistency between write/commands and read/query.

This also works if you have your Readmodels coupled to each other, i.e. one Readmodel needs data from another canonical Readmodel. Although this seems bad, it's not, it always depends. There are cases when you trade updater code/logic duplication with resilience.

2. **Asynchronous, in-another-process** readmodel updater. This is used when I use total separation of the Readmodel from the other Readmodels, when a Readmodel's failure would not bring the whole read-side down; or when a Readmodel needs another language, different from the monolith. Basically this is a microservice. When something bad happens inside a Readmodel it necessary that some authoritative higher level component is notified, i.e. an Admin is notified by email or SMS or whatever.

The Readmodel should also have a status panel, with all kinds of metrics about the events that it has processed, if there are gaps, if there are errors or warnings; it also should have a command panel where an Admin could rebuild it at any time, preferable without a system downtime.

In any approach, the Readmodels should be easily rebuildable.

> How would you choose between a pull approach and a push approach? Would you use a message queue with a push (events)

I prefer the pull based approach because:

- it does not use another stateful component like a message queue, another thing that must be managed, that consume resources and that can (so it will) fail
- every Readmodel consumes the events at the rate it wants
- every Readmodel can easily change at any moment what event types it consumes
- every Readmodel can easily at any time be rebuild by requesting all the events from the beginning
- there order of events is exactly the same as the source of truth because you pull from the source of truth

There are cases when I would choose a message queue:

- you need the events to be available even if the Event store is not
- you need competitive/paralel consumers
- you don't want to track what messages you consume; as they are consumed they are removed automatically from the queue

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the comprehenive answer.  When you say: "Basically this is a microservice"; I assume there is a separate microservice for the read model and a separate microservice for the write model with a message queue, which contains WriteRecordCreated events to be handled by the read model microservice.  Is that right?

Comment: @w0051977 yes, separate microservices for the write and read; the events are Domain events, they are not named `WriteRecordCreated`.

Comment: 1) Shouldn't they be integration events if there are separate microservices? 2) I guess you are criticising my naming convention in the last comment - I guess OrderCreated or PersonCreated is better than WriteRecordCreated?

Comment: @w0051977 1) yes, they are integration events that wrap domain events

Comment: @w0051977 2) yes, every event comes with a specific type, they are not named generic

Comment: Finally, is there any correlation between 'push and pull' and 'synchronous and non-asynchronous'.  For example, push is used with asynchronous.  I have not really thought about this before.

Comment: Can you answer the sub question in my last comment? - that should clear everything up.  Then I will mark the answer.

Comment: @w0051977 what question, could you repeat it again here?

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a relationship between 'push and pull' and 'synchronous and asynchronous'? 1) is it "better" to use push with synchronous or push with asynchronous 2) is it "better" to use pull with synchronous or pull with asynchronous 3) It makes no difference.  1,2 or 3?

Comment: @w0051977 is hard to answer that. However, if you want resilience then you should not have synchronous messaging between remote systems, it leads to a distributed monolith. By synchronous I mean to send a request and wait for a response in the same process, no mater if the call is synch or asynch from the programming language point of view

Comment: Finally I was reading some of your other CQRS answers over the weekend (nice answers by the way) and I notice you occasionally refer to an event log as an alternative to an event store.  Can you confirm that an event log is just a table e.g. SQL table containing persisted aggregate events e.g. an SQL Server table.

Comment: @w0051977 yes, can be a SQL table but the important thing to notice is that it is not the source of truth for the write model but for the read model only. (otherwise it would be an Event store)

Comment: I did see that in one of your other answers i.e. the single source of truth was a relational database.  What does event store add that an event log does not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180191/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-w0051977).

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: If you would like to look at the follow on question I asked yesterday then please do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382927/what-is-an-aggregate-function.

Comment: if you could have a look at my question here then I would be grateful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386478/cqrs-with-an-event-log-and-without-event-sourcing?noredirect=1#comment850282_386478.  It is similar to this one.  Perhaps I should of just added a comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This talk from [Greg Young](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv2dKtPq0ME&t=24m55s) may help.

> How does the application know to replay the 950 events that are missing at the end of the day or the x events that were missed because of the downtime ten minutes ago?

So there are two different approaches here.

One is perhaps simpler than you expect - each time you need to rebuild a read model, just start from event 0 in the stream.

Yeah, the scale on that will eventually suck, so you won't want that to be your first strategy.  But notice that it does work.

For updates with not-so-embarassing scaling properties, the usual idea is that the read model tracks meta data about stream position used to construct the previous model.  Thus, the query from the read model becomes "What has happened since event #1,999,050"?

In the case of [event store](https://eventstore.org/docs/dotnet-api/reading-events/index.html), the call might look something like

```
EventStore.ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync(stream, 1999050, 100, false)
```

Comment: Is the read store updated by handling an event that is created after the write store is updated or does the read store ask for events that were created since event x? I am still trying to get my head around the mechanics of this. Thanks for the video - I will upvote once I have watched it tomorrow.

Comment: https://barryosull.com/blog/projection-building-blocks-what-you-ll-need-to-build-projections - check Projector Position Ledger - this is a metadata for the read model.
We record an aggregate ID and number of events applied for every aggregate.

Comment: @Roman Wrekin, how do i access the next article in that series? Please see the last paragraph in that article, which references how to trigger a projection.  That is the point of my question.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess this is a list of all post of that blog: https://barryosull.com/blog (It is not mine blog)

Answer (score 1):

Application doesn't know it hasn't processed some events due to a bug.

First of all, I don't understand why you assume that the number of events written on the write side must equal number of events processed by read side. Some projections may subscribe to the same event and some events may have no subscriptions on the read side.

In case of a bug in projection / infrastructure that resulted in a certain projection being invalid you might need to rebuild this projection. In most cases this would be a manual intervention that would reset the checkpoint of projection to 0 (begining of time) so the projection will pick up all events from event store from scratch and reprocess all of them again.

Comment: Is the read store updated by handling an event that is created after the write store is updated or does the read store ask for events that were created since event x? I am still trying to get my head around the mechanics of this.  Thanks.

Comment: Both approaches are valid. If you use checkpointing than you would prefer a pull model.

Comment: My point is that if a push approach is used I.e events - then the two models could become quickly out of sync.     Is there a way to prevent this (with events?.  Would I have to use a message queue/bus? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think they will 'quickly become out of sync'? I assume you have unit tests for your projections and test them. What is the likelihood a bug will slip into production?

Comment: Unlikely, what if the server goes down just after the write model is appended and just before the read model is updated (when using events).  Would I need a message queue/bus for eventual consistency?

Comment: Yes, you will need a reliable messaging solution here.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I believe the consensus is against a message bus.  See the video link in the other answer.  I cannot understand this as it surely means the two databases will become out of sync.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but highly unlikely. What are the chances that the node will go down right between storing the event and writing it into the queue (remember that Greg is selling his EventStore). However, I agree that pull model is safer. Take a look at CosmosDB change feed - getting notifications from database when the event has been written is a preferred approach for me.

Comment: Do you know of any code which demonstrates a pull model using cqrs (whatever databases are used and whatever language - c# preferable).  +1 by the way.

Comment: That depends on the database: EventStore (https://eventstore.org/docs/dotnet-api/competing-consumers/index.html), CosmosDB (search for change feed)

Comment: @w0051977 `Do you know of any code which demonstrates a pull model using cqrs (whatever databases are used and whatever language - c# preferable)`  take a look at https://github.com/xprt64/mongolina-js/blob/master/Readme.md (it's mine)

Comment: @Constantin Galbenu, I wilk review that code later thanks.  How would you choose between a pull approach and a push approach? Would you use a message queue with a push (events)? The video posted in the other answer appears to advise against it.

Answer (score 1):

The event store should have a global sequence number across all events starting, say, at 1.

Each projection has a position tracking where it is along the sequence number.  The projections are like *logical* queues.

You can clear a projection's data and reset the position back to 0 and it should be rebuilt.

In your case the projection fails for some reason, like the server going offline, at position 1,999,050 but when the server starts up again it will continue from this point.

Comment: This is usually a problem for concurrent command execution, and really not necessary. You'll need a sequence number per aggregate stream.

Comment: How would you track which events were processed by the projection then? You'd basically need `(ProjectionId,AggregateId,LatestVersion)` entries stored which seems much more difficult than relying on a global sequence number, no? I know that you can't use an identity field as a global sequence number with a SQL-backed ES, but some work arounds I've seen is to use a single sequencer thread responsible to update the `global_sequence_number` after the event was inserted `ORDER BY identity, aggregate_id, version` or something like that.

Comment: @RomanEremin: each event has the aggregate id along with a `Version`.  The `SequenceNumber` is global across all events.  As @plaix mentions: I don't quite see how you'd track those projections without such a sequence number.

Comment: @EbenRoux: we are using the approach described by plaix above. Global sequence is simpler in single central DB scenario, but creates a bottleneck for concurrent commands, and will be even more problematic in any distributed scenario.

Comment: Any identity (or sequence number) in a data store will cause a hot spot, agreed.  However, there are pros and cons to any design.  This sequence number, for me anyway, is going to be one of the cons for ES.  Now, I'm all for distribution but exactly how do you ensure that an event is projected in the correct sequence?  Tracking the projection on `(projection,aggregate,version)` seems unwieldy.  I am no expert on the matter so it would be interesting to see different approaches/strategies.  Do you perhaps have an example somewhere (perhaps on github) that I can take a look at?