# What is an Aggregate Function?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I am trying to learn Event Sourcing (using Greg Youngs Event Store) in my spare time.  I have setup a simple stream and I can read from it and write to it.

Please see this link: https://eventstore.org/docs/getting-started/?tabs=tabid-1%2Ctabid-dotnet-client%2Ctabid-dotnet-client-connect%2Ctabid-4.  It says:

"If you are Event Sourcing a domain model, a stream equates to an aggregate function."

I don't believe I have ever come across the term Aggregate Function before - I know aggregate root and aggregate, however not aggregate function.  Say I have the events below:

```
BookingCreatedEvent
BookingUpdatedEvent
```

If I was to create an event log in SQL server then it could look something like this (the Cargo column contains the serialized object):

[image]

What Event streams would I have in Event Store for this? I was reading an answer from a user on here who seems to be very knowledgeable about Event Sourcing and he suggested the following:

```
AggregateType+AggregateId+Version
```

On that basis believe the events would be named as follows:

```
BookingCreatedEvent511 (51 is the aggregate ID and 1 is the version)
BookingUpdatedEvent511 (51 is the aggregate ID and 1 is the version)
BookingUpdatedEvent512 (51 is the aggregate ID and 2 is the version)
BookingCreatedEvent521 (52 is the aggregate ID and 1 is the version)
BookingUpdatedEvent513 (51 is the aggregate ID and 3 is the version)
BookingCreatedEvent531 (53 is the aggregate ID and 1 is the version)
BookingUpdatedEvent514 (51 is the aggregate ID and 4 is the version)
BookingUpdatedEvent515 (51 is the aggregate ID and 5 is the version)
BookingUpdatedEvent516 (51 is the aggregate ID and 6 is the version)
BookingUpdatedEvent517 (51 is the aggregate ID and 7 is the version)
```

Therefore there are 10 event streams.  This looks a little confusing i.e. concatenating the aggregate ID and version - for example, say I had the following:

```
  BookingUpdatedEvent51745
```

How would I know what part of 51745 is the aggregate ID and what part is the version.

Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: **rolls his eyes** `BookingCreatedEvent511 ` isn't unique... `51+1` and `5+11` creates the same result. You should use at least dashes to separate it

Comment: Also if you are using SQL database you don't have to put it all into the same column, use separate one and a unique constraint on it. You only need to concatenate if you only have a single indexed column  (or only partition key / row key), such as in Azure Table Storage

Comment: @ingen, thanks.  +1.  So what would the event streams be called in this case? Can you post an answer so I can give some credit?

Comment: By aggregate function I think the text refers to the act of an event handler function at the aggregate root level to reconstitute the aggregate state. So you will be N handles depending on how many event types you got in your domain model for that specific aggregate.

Comment: I understand this part as: "you have one event stream per one aggregate instance".

Comment: @Roman Eremin, so if there are 1 million Bookings and each Booking has 1 or more events (1 for added and x for updated), then there will be 1 million event streams for Booking - even though a Booking can have more than one event.  Is that right?

Comment: Aggregate function in this case has nothing to do with Domain Driven Design, but rather a mathematical way of looking at what event sourcing is. An aggregate function such as "IEnumerable.Sum" will aggregate values in a collection. In functional terms, you might hear that state is simply a left fold of the event stream. As such, the current state is a summation, an aggregation of the input events.

Comment: @w0051977, yes - to restore a Booking's state you'll need to read exatly one stream of events.

Comment: @Roman Eremin, does one stream contains one Booking? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977, one aggregate would require one event stream to restore its state. If your aggregate - Booking, then to restore its state (to be able to execute a command), you'll need all events for this booking and a function that reduces these events to the aggregate state. So you'll need all events for given aggregate ID in one place - thus you'll need one event stream for the given aggregate id

Comment: @w0051977, so in your example, event stream for aggregate 51 will be  `select Action, Cargo from events where AggregatID=51 order by TimeStamp`

Comment: @Roman Eremin, thanks.  However, I am asking how this would be represented inside EventStore.  Would stream 1 have all the events for Booking 1 and stream x have all the booking for booking x?

Comment: Aggregate stream = all the events emitted by the same `AggregateType+AggregateId`; I never said `AggregateType+AggregateId+Version`, I said that this is the unique index that a stream should have

Comment: @Constantin Galbenu, thanks again.  I understand that to mean there will be three streams i.e. 51,52 and 53.

Comment: @w0051977 yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are Event Sourcing a domain model, a stream equates to an aggregate function

I can't find any evidence that means anything.

The original text of that section of the document, committed by Dan Leech in 2014, used this spelling

> If you are Event Sourcing a domain model a stream would equate to an aggregate.

The commit where Chris made the change is [available in github](https://github.com/EventStore/documentation/commit/2be5b7308baf00f2906670eeae32ba8629164290), but it's mixed in with a major rewrite, so there's no documented explanation for the change.

> Say I had an Aggregate of order (containing order items) and there were 1 million of them, then I would have 1 million streams instead of 1

Basically, yes.

More precisely, each stream is logically isolated from all of the others; Event Store doesn't give you facilities to make atomic changes to more than one stream at a time.

So each immediately consistent transaction in your domain model should be writing to exactly one event stream.

Comment: Just to be clear.  Say I had an Aggregate of order (containing order items) and there were 1 million of them, then I would have 1 million streams instead of 1?

Comment: Thanks +1 for the edit.  In that case I would have: Booking1; Booking2; Booking3 etc.  I have looked at this: https://github.com/dcomartin/EventStore.CompetingConsumers.Demo/blob/master/src/PersistentSubscription/Program.cs.  It allows you to subscribe to 1 stream i.e. a_test_stream.  Say I wanted to subscribe to all Booking streams.  Would I use categories for this?

Comment: That's a question you should probably ask separately; subscription management has different constraints/trade offs than maintaining aggregate state.

Comment: OK, I will do some more reading and ask if necessary.  Before I accept; would the aggregates be: 1) Booking1, Booking2, Bookingx 2) Booking+1, Booking+2, Booking+x 3) Booking-1, Booking-2, Booking-3.  The reason I ask is because my reading implies that - means something in Event Store.